# How to fix issue "Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer'" when running "pkg ."

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, exe

so I have a puppeteer script and I want to make it a .exe file that includes node_modules within the .exe file.

index.js:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");

const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

code...
```

When I run `pkg .` it creates the .exe files but I have to run it besides the node_modules folder to be able to run it without having the error `" Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer'"`

I also tried this on my package.json

```
  "pkg": {
    "assets": "node_modules/**/*.*"
  },
```

But it has been like an hour or so, and nothing has been created, it's like it has frozen.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const isPkg = typeof process.pkg !== 'undefined';

const chromiumExecutablePath = isPkg 
    ? puppeteer.executablePath().replace(
        /^.*?\/node_modules\/puppeteer\/\.local-chromium/,
        path.join(path.dirname(process.execPath), '.local-chromium')
      ) : puppeteer.executablePath()
);
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   executablePath: chromiumExecutablePath,
   args: [
     "--start-maximized",
     "--no-sandbox",
   ],
   headless: false,
   defaultViewport: null
})
```

And to build use npm script like:

```
"build": "pkg src/index.js --public --targets node14-win-x64 --out-path dist"
```

Comment: I get an error: "Failed to launch the browser process" and that it cannot find the chrome.exe file on the .local-chromium folder

Comment: Specifically: ```Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /snapshot/FT Auto Login Bot #2/node_modules/puppeteer-core/.local-chromium/mac-1045629/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium ENOENT```

Comment: @Mike  try with args: ["--no-sandbox", "--start-maximized"]

Comment: What is process.pkg? It said that Property 'pkg' does not exist on type 'Process'.

Comment: @Mike I have same error, have you fixed it?